# How to get from post_class from relationship (related)

Tags: wordpress

I have created two custom post types, 'offers' and 'brands'. I have made the relationship using an advanced custom fields relationship field 'related_brand'.

Each brand uses a single post and the related posts are shown on the same page, however, when using post_class on the related posts I just noticed they are displaying the brands post classes and not the related posts classes, which are different.

How can I pull in the correct post_class for the related posts bearing in mind they are two separate post types.

The following pulls in the related posts.

```
$offers = get_posts(array(
        'post_type' => 'offers', // name of custom post type
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'related_brand', // name of custom field
                'value' => '"' . get_the_ID() . '"', 
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            )
        )
    ));
```

Watered down code that displays the related posts.

```
<?php if ($offers) : ?>
<?php foreach ($offers as $offer) : ?>
<div <?php post_class(); ?>> <!--Displaying the incorrect post classes-->
    <div>   
        <a href="<?php the_permalink($offer->ID); ?>">
            <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($offer->ID,); ?>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div>  
        <a href="<?php the_permalink($offer->ID); ?>">
            <?php echo get_the_title($offer->ID); ?>
        </a>
    </div>      
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In his case he is taking the post_class with the id of the current loop and not that of foreach but of the current loop of the tag.

To get it right you should use post_class with two arguments post_class ('', $ post_id); where the second is the post id. In your case the code should be + - like this:

```
<?php if ($offers) : ?>
<?php foreach ($offers as $offer) : ?>
<div <?php post_class('', $offer->ID ); ?>> <!--Displaying the incorrect post classes-->
    <div>   
        <a href="<?php the_permalink($offer->ID); ?>">
            <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($offer->ID,); ?>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div>  
        <a href="<?php the_permalink($offer->ID); ?>">
            <?php echo get_the_title($offer->ID); ?>
        </a>
    </div>      
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```